# Very strong owner password encryption for text files?

Tags: encryption

Does anyone knows about software with encryption of owner password stronger than 254 bit? More than 500 or 1000 bit? Algorithm may be AES or other one. It's necessary to protect my copyright laws.
   I need this software to create text files in pdf, rtf or in other kind of text format, file. To publish them in the internet.
   This software should be for Win system and in freeware, open source or in similar licenses.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What qualifications or references do you have to make the claim that you require "stronger than 254 bit" encryption?  Giving a bit size is arbitrary without an algorithm. With respect, I feel like your knowledge on this topic isn't advanced enough for you to actually understand what you do or don't need.

Comment: maybe https://ssh-vault.com/ cross-platform so can create in windows, decrypt in *nix like

Comment: What is an "owner password?" Where will you be storing the key for this encryption? (Key management is much more important than key length in almost all cases.) What does it mean to "protect my copyright laws?" Key length is not an independently meaningful metric for encryption strength. It is generally meaningful when comparing two versions of one algorithm, but it cannot be used to compare different algorithms; a 256-bit elliptic key, for example, is comparable in strength to a 3072-bit RSA key (this does not imply that RSA is weak; it simply requires longer keys).

Comment: AES with a 256-bit key (when used correctly) is some of the strongest cryptography in the world. What problem do you have that you believe it's not sufficient for?

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the quality of the key.

A 128-bit random AES key can not be brute forced so that is all that is necessary. AES supports only three key sizes: 128, 192 & 256 bits. You will also want to use a mode such as CBC or GCM with a random per encryption IV.

If a password is being used the encryption key needs to be derived from it, for that use PBKDF2, Argon2 or similar with a CPU work factor of ~100ms or greater. Verify that the password/passphrase is not on a list of frequently used passwords such as at [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords).